# Clearcase: list all changed files between 2 baselines

Tags: clearcase

I want to know all files that changed between 2 baselines. I need to have a list in text.  Through the interface I need to enter in each activity of baseline. In this dialog, I list the files, but can't copy the names to a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal command is:

```
cleartool diffbl -ver baseline1@\apvob baseline2@\apvob
```

But be aware it will list all the versions changed between the two baselines, not just the elements (files or directory).
That means a file could be listed multiple times, because multiple versions of said files have changed between the two baselines.

That [old thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000002916405) mentions a potential solution (not tested) in order to list the elements (files or directories) only once.

```perl
my %elem = map {
  tr|\\|/|; # Convert slashes to unix style.
  s|^<< M:/^/+/^/+/||; # Drop view tag and vob tag.
  s|\@\@.*||; # Drop branch and version id.
  $_ => 1; # Pick up the path.
} qx(cleartool diffbl -version -first $laterbl $olderbl);
print sort keys %elem;
```

The [OP neves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335/neves) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558999/clearcase-list-all-changed-files-between-2-baselines#comment25545086_17559296) that this idea works, with:

```sh
cleartool diffbl -ver baseline_abc.123@\\MYVOB baseline_abc.358@\\MYVOB | \
  awk -F '\\' '{print $8}' |grep @@|sort| uniq|sed 's/@@//'
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine. Another simple thing that is hard in ClearCase. Here is my bash script to get just the filenames:  cleartool diffbl -ver baseline_abc.123@\\MYVOB baseline_abc.358@\\MYVOB |awk -F '\\' '{print $8}' |grep  @@|sort|
uniq|sed 's/@@//'

Comment: @neves Excellent. I have included your one-liner command in the answer for more visibility.